# Tidying tags for Open Source GIS and Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC)?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

When thinking about Open Source GIS and the Open Geospatial Consortium, we currently have these tags:

- [open-gis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-gis) with 5 questions
- [open-source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) with 394 question
- [ogc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ogc) with 68 questions

Do we need to tidy these tags and how?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main source of ambiguity is the [open-gis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-gis) tag which seems more often to be used for the Open Geospatial Consortium but sometimes for Open Source GIS.

To disambiguate it and tidy up the other mentioned tags into something easier to work with I am going to suggest:

1. Merging [open-source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) into a new tag called [open-source-gis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source-gis) which would leave [open-source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) as a synonym.  There may be some questions here that are about Open Source software other than Open Source GIS but I think they are few and far between, and will only be peripheral to the questions they are placed on.  For example, a Python question may have been tagged [open-source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) but more likely it is tagged [python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) anyway.  If the focus of a question is about Open Source software other than Open Source GIS it is probably off topic anyway.
2. Retagging any [open-gis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-gis) questions about Open Source GIS to [open-source-gis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source-gis) - I think there is only one
3. Merging any remaining [open-gis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-gis) questions into [ogc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ogc) which would leave [open-gis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-gis) as a synonym.

Comment: Ogc is very different to open source. Ill add more when i get to a real keyboard.

Comment: @iant Of course - hence the need for disambiguating [tag:open-gis] which is currently spanning them

Comment: sorry - I should have waited for a proper screen as well as a keyboard.